# What is the recommended library for using Lua from C++?

Tags: c++, lua

I am currently planning how to integrate Lua scripting in my 2D Game Engine, and i would like to go straight to the most adequate solution for having C++ classes and objects exposed.

I've read this (if it helps you help): http://lua-users.org/wiki/BindingCodeToLua

If you have a better scripting language to recomend, go for it ;D

All help is welcome, i need to pickup the best solution to start implementing 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the primary quality of your scripting language is easy binding, try [AngelScript](http://www.angelcode.com/angelscript/). It can call registered functions directly without the need to write proxy functions, and it supports calling conventions of wide variety of compilers. The language itself is similar to c/c++, which may be a good or a bad thing, depending.

Answer (score 7):

I've heard good things about [LuaPlus](http://luaplus.org/). It wraps the low level C API into a higher level C++ one.

Answer (score 4):

As long as you're doing reasonably conventional binding, [LuaBind](http://www.rasterbar.com/products/luabind.html) will do everything you need. Binding classes and functions tends to be a one-line-per-function deal. If you'd like an example, [here's](https://github.com/zorbathut/glorp/blob/master/core.cpp) the applicable file from the game engine I've been working on (look for module(L) for the start of the LuaBind interface, DontKillMeBro<> is a little system I rigged up to let me more precisely time object destruction for certain sensitive objects.)

If you want something more complex, you're probably going to need to use the actual Lua API. Luckily, the Lua API is reasonably simple.

Answer (score 1):

We're using [OOLua](http://code.google.com/p/oolua/) for [Pioneer](http://pioneerspacesim.net/). It gives a pile of macros that you use to bind Lua "classes" to C++ classes. Its got a fair bit of power but is pretty straightforward. I haven't used any others so I can't comment on how it compares. Here's an [example](https://github.com/tomm/pioneer/blob/aafdcbd/src/StarSystem.h#L75).

Answer (score 1):

I'd go hands down with [Nuclex's](http://www.nuclex.org/articles/5-cxx/1-quick-introduction-to-luabind) precompiled libs and include files for LuaBind. (that is if you're working with VS2008)

Since LuaBind requires you to build it with some Boost libs and tools, this package will save you valuable time (and maybe some headache, who knows). I'd say you'd be able to get Lua running in less than an hour if you know what you're doing.

You may also consider changing the default Lua dll to a [LuaJIT](http://luajit.org) dll if you're looking for a [small performance gain](http://luajit.org/performance.html). It's only a matter of compiling the library and replacing the lib/dll you're linking against in your main project, so it's quite easy.

With that, good luck!